# What's a low depth floor joist solution for 2nd floor with 4x4 floor joists?

Tags: ceiling, floor, joists

My goal is to meet the code requirement for the strength of the floors on a 2nd story for a remodel.

I am remodeling a house where the floor joists supporting the 2nd floor are nominal 4x4 (3.5" x 3.5"). My problem is that by adding lumber of the correct depth (presumably 2x8) the ceiling height will be too low for taste, and potentially for code. The current ceiling height measured to the joist is 7' 10". My goal is to keep the current ceiling height by using aluminum or other metal as low depth joists to strengthen the floor (fitting into the current 3.5" depth).

I'm not an engineer, but I think my problem is that I'm exceeding L/360 deflection limit. Here's the scenario:

The 2nd floor area is a 23' x 20' rectangle (rounding up to the nearest foot). The floor joists run along the 23' length toward the center of the home, and they sit on top of a wall and beam combo with a 3.5" bearing. The joists run to 10' 6" on one side then sit on the wall/beam, and they run 12' 5" on the other side before they lap over the wall/beam. The 4x4 joists are placed at 13" on center. Very odd. Apparently, the 2nd story addition happened in the 70's and survived the 89 earthquake in Oakland CA.

What are your suggestions for keeping the current floor depth, but strengthening the floors so as to reduce deflection specifically, but more generally to meet code requirements for floor strength?

I was thinking of inserting some 3.5" x3.5" aluminum joists alongside the 4x4 lumber to increase strength and reduce deflection.

Comment: It would open a lot of options if you could bump height to nominal 2x6. A 7' 6" ceiling still isn't terrible by any means, and you'll have a much easier time finding solutions if you can spare 5-1/2". I'd consider doubled 2x6 on 12" centers.

Comment: Aluminum would be _extremely_ expensive. If anything you'd probably use a steel C-channel or box, but you'd need an engineer's stamp of approval.

Comment: Even steel beams get their strength from the depth of the web.  On paper, I suspect S3x7.5 I-beams could do that span as floor joists, but on top of costing $200 each, you then have to attach subfloor to the steel flange?  On the other hand, 2x6 Structural Select lumber would probably work with normal construction methods.

Comment: I meant [something more like this](https://www.clarkdietrich.com/sites/default/files/styles/product_profile_main/public/content/product/images/profile/TD.jpg), not full-on I-beams.

Comment: FYI - 4x4s are almost twice as good as carrying a floor load, but almost half as good as a 2x6.   There is that big of a difference.    If no architect signs off on it I would take the 4x4 out of equation.

Comment: I am curious on the reticence of just picking up the phone and calling the building inspector and asking?  Our taxes pay for them to answer this kind of a question.

Comment: @isherwood steel studs won't carry a load like that.  If you just turn it on its side the web isn't thick enough; it would crumple.  Imagine a cardboard paper towel tube as a column: it's pretty strong, you could balance a brick on it.  If you lay the tube on the ground and try to use it to support a brick over a span like a beam or joist, the tube will deform.

Comment: That's not a stud. It's a [purpose-built joist](https://www.clarkdietrich.com/products/tradeready-joist-system/tradeready-steel-joist).

Comment: I agree with Isherwood channel iron heavy wall would be the only way I would believe a 4” joist would meet code. I work in a lumber mill and today’s wood is not even close to the 70’s  I have photos of 4x4 grade 2 with a swirl 5 knots the limbs visible on that board I don’t know if that would span a foot with the swirl in the middle. today we literary turn Christmas trees into lumber. You are also in a seismic zone, I don’t know how the 4x4 passed in the first place it had to be done without permits I was building back then and 4x4 would not have passed for a window header of 4’.

Comment: @dmoore I would disagree on the strength of a 4x4  being that strong unless you get ladder stock or vertical grain wood. My plant specializes in small log recovery but we also have a band mill that we cut large logs unless the 4x4 is  quarter sawn and properly oriented the 2x6 will be much stronger than 2x. The optimizers target heart wood for 4x4 on smaller trees since most 4x4 are posts. The quarter sawn outside wood is where the beams are made even on smaller logs.

Comment: @EdBeal - I agree that there is a high variation but if you just go by generic architectural load standards those are the numbers you get - I have seen these numbers many many times.    There are metal braces for the 4x4s that can make it strong than a 2x6... but this is costly and not as straight forward as you think.

Comment: I have never used anything that small on a 10’ span and don’t know how it is holding up (I would not want to walk on it) but I am a really big guy.